# Vbscript Month and Second Function to 3 decimal places

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to write a vbscript that will write the date and time into a config file in specific way. I have been researching the web and have not been able to locate how to format the seconds function correctly. Not even sure if it is possible. Any help or references would be greatly appreciated. My question is, Is there a way to format the Month and Seconds Function so that month will display as MM if single number month and second will display 3 decimal places?

Here is what I have tried so far but it is invalid.

```
myDate = (Year(Now) & "-" & Month(date) & "-" & day(date) & "T" & Hour(Time) & ":" & Minute(time) & ":" & Second(time) ' Displays as YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS

second = FormatNumber(Second, 3)

write.write(myDate)
```

I need it to display as YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a pad function to pad with extra zero's. Use the timer for capturing the milliseconds.

```
Option Explicit
Dim timerNow, myNow, myDate

timerNow = cStr(cdbl(timer))
myNow = now()

myDate = (Year(myNow) & "-" & _
    zeropad(Month(myNow),2) & "-" & _
    zeroPad(day(myNow),2) & "T" & _
    zeroPad(Hour(myNow),2) & ":" & _
    zeroPad(Minute(myNow),2) & ":" & _ 
    zeroPad(Second(myNow),2) & "." & _
    left(split(timerNow, ".")(1),3)) ' Displays as YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS


Private Function zeroPad(byval strInput, byval padCount)
    If len(strInput) < padCount Then
        zeroPad = string(padCount - len(strInput), "0") & strInput
    Else
        zeroPad = strInput
    End If
End Function
```

One thing could go wrong here: When the time is just jumping from n.999 to n+1.000 when `myNow` and `timerNow` are retrieved. Idealiter you would extract myNow from timerNow, but that is left as an exercize for the reader.

Answer (score 2):

[Now() Accuracy in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239169/now-accuracy-in-vbscript)

It seems in vbscript the "Now()" function can be converted to double to provide this type of precision.

Answer (score 1):

```
CStr(Year(Date())) & "-" & Right("0" & CStr(Month(Date())), 2) & "-" & Right("0" & CStr(Day(Date())), 2)
```

This code will create YYYY-MM-DD

I think you get the idea and will be able to add the time component yourself